# Nested JSON and AngularJS confusion

Tags: php, angularjs, web

Basically I have a PHP quasi-API that results in this JSON:

```
{"0":{"id":"325","course":"{\"0\":{\"id\":\"31\",\"title\":\"Ticket Seller     II\",\"code\":\"STN\"},\"nm\":1}","batch":"29","start_date":"2016-04-20 08:30:00","end_date":"2016-05-17 17:00:00"}}
```

But while I retrieved the first JSON array by the JS script:

```
var prog=[];
var res=response.data;

for(var i=0; i<=res['nm'];i++){


     prog.push(res[i]);

}

vm.events = prog;
```

I have no idea how to retrieve the nested JSON, "course".   I have this Angular script:

```
ng-repeat="event in table1.events"
```

But something like event.course[0].title gives out an error.   Nesting a repeat like

```
<span ng-repeat="title in event.course">
```

Still doesn't work.  How do I retrieve it?

I've tried the following:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="event in table1.events">
    <td>{{ event.course }}<pre ng-repeat="value in event.course">{{ value.title }} 5664</pre>  </td>
 </tr>
```

And it doesn't work.  the 5664 doesn't appear, but the event.course shows the JSON snippet.  It's as if the snippet is not being read as JSON.

UPDATE: Sorry, it works now.  I didn't see the solution work because the first few rows really had empty content, but it works now.

Comment: Something's wrong with the `json`.

Comment: i didn't close the snippet.  i copied and pasted a snippet because it was a long JSON that listed all the rows within a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ng-repeat` nested,Please see the code below.it may help you to figure it out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <span ng-repeat="item in events">
    <span ng-repeat="value in item.course">
      <!-- if you want to get title alone -->
      <pre>{{value.title}}</pre>
    </span>
  </span>
</body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.events = {
      "0": {
        "id": "325",
        "course": {
          "0": {
            "id ": "31",
            "title": "Ticket Seller II",
            "code": "STN "
          },
          "nm ": "1"
        },
        "batch": "29",
        "start_date": "2016-04-20 08:30:00",
        "end_date": "2016-05-17 17:00:00"
      },

      "1": {
        "id": "325",
        "course": {
          "0": {
            "id ": "31",
            "title": "card Seller II",
            "code": "STN "
          },
          "nm ": "1"
        },
        "batch": "29",
        "start_date": "2016-04-20 08:30:00",
        "end_date": "2016-05-17 17:00:00"
      }


    }
  });
</script>

</html>
```

see code is working for span also.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <span ng-repeat="item in events">
    <span ng-repeat="value in item.course">
      <!-- if you want to get title alone -->
      <span>{{value.title}}</br></span>
    </span>
  </span>
</body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.events = {
      "0": {
        "id": "325",
        "course": {
          "0": {
            "id ": "31",
            "title": "Ticket Seller II",
            "code": "STN "
          },
          "nm ": "1"
        },
        "batch": "29",
        "start_date": "2016-04-20 08:30:00",
        "end_date": "2016-05-17 17:00:00"
      },

      "1": {
        "id": "325",
        "course": {
          "0": {
            "id ": "31",
            "title": "card Seller II",
            "code": "STN "
          },
          "nm ": "1"
        },
        "batch": "29",
        "start_date": "2016-04-20 08:30:00",
        "end_date": "2016-05-17 17:00:00"
      }


    }
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: actually thats what i did.  i used span instead of pre. but i will try again.

Comment: That doesn't matter.This snippet will work for both `pre` and `span`

Comment: i tried testing <span ng-repeat="item in event.course">{{ item.title }} Test</span> and neither the test text or the item.title appears.  But if instead of the span I write event.course, it shows the entire JSON snippet

Comment: okay, my mistake.  it worked, but i didnt see the entries because the first few entries really did NOT have any content/data.  thanks it works now

Answer (score 0):

You `JSON`is missing a `}` at the end

```
{  
   "0":{  
      "id":"325",
      "course":"{\"0\":{\"id\":\"31\",\"title\":\"Ticket Seller     II\",\"code\":\"STN\"},\"nm\":1}",
      "batch":"29",
      "start_date":"2016-04-20 08:30:00",
      "end_date":"2016-05-17 17:00:00"
   }
}
```

[image]

Use a validator to check validity of your JSON. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: sorry, i copied and pasted a snippet, but it was a longer JSON, with closed }.  i should've at least closed the snippet; though the problem was with the angular.